# SQL - Select one record randomly per person

Tags: mysql, sql, transactions

I currently have one table containing details of 100 people's first transactions with each product in the transaction as a separate record. Some people only bought 1 product in their first transaction while others may have bought up to 4 different products in their first transaction.

I'd like to create a table containing 1 distinct record per person where if they had purchased multiple different products in their first transaction, I'm randomly selecting one of those products. How would I go about doing this in mySQL?

Comment: How "random", and which sql? `sql-server` usually indicates MS SQL Server, which is not the same as MySQL.

Comment: The answer depends greatly on your answer to which DBMS you are using. And in the database world don't confuse a customer's purchase with a transaction, they are very different things.

Comment: You need to provide more information about your data schema as well. Are these records in one table? Is there a primary key? You may need to write a query with a sub query to achieve your goal.

Comment: It's MySQL and these records are in one table. There isn't a primary key in this table either

Comment: @J.Doe, I've added the [tag:mysql] tag. In the future, it's a good idea to tag your question with the brand of RDBMS you use, because it will attract attention from the people who can best answer your question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Suppose your table is like this:

```
CREATE TABLE MyTable (
  person_id INT,
  product_id INT,
  transaction_date DATE
);
```

It might have other columns too, but I'm not going to guess at them.

I would do this by "shuffling" the rows for each person. Sort the table by person first, then randomize the rows for the given person. You can do this by using `ORDER BY person_id, RAND()`.

Then pick the first row for each person. This is a way to do this, using MySQL session variables to track the row number and start the row numbering from 1 with each distinct person_id:

```
SELECT person_id, product_id, transaction_date
FROM (
    SELECT IF(@p=person_id, @r:=@r+1, 1) AS row_num
      @p:=person_id AS person_id, product_id, transaction_date
    FROM (SELECT @p:=0, @r:=0) AS _init
    CROSS JOIN MyTable
    ORDER BY person_id, RAND()
) AS T
WHERE row_num = 1;
```

When MySQL 8.0 comes out (probably in 2018), it should implement windowing functions, which will make this a little more standard:

```
SELECT person_id, product_id, transaction_date
FROM (
    SELECT ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY person_id ORDER BY RAND()) AS row_num,
        person_id, product_id, transaction_date
    FROM MyTable
) AS T
WHERE row_num = 1;
```

P.S.: By the way, when you ask questions about SQL, you should run `SHOW CREATE TABLE MyTable` and include the result in your question. It helps people not have to guess about your table, columns, indexes, data types, etc. They may be able to write an example that is closer to what you need.

Comment: Thank you! This exactly answered my question. I'll keep your tip in mind for future questions too - thank you so much!